# Add delay to publisher based on value with Combine Framework in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I have one publisher
`public let motionSubject = PassthroughSubject<Bool, Never>()`

And i am listening values with

```
motionManager.motionSubject.sink(receiveValue: { [weak self] isMoving in
    self?.isMoving = isMoving
}).store(in: &subscription)
```

I want to add 2 seconds delay if the published value is "true" because I want to give 2 seconds sound feedback.

I tried to add DispatchQueue.asynafter before motionSubject.send(true) but it didn't work.

Is anyone know how can i achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to add the delay to changing `isMoving` or do you want to delay subsequent values from `motionSubject` as well? So what should happen if `motionSubject` emits `true`, then 1s later it emits another value (be it `true` or `false`)?

Comment: Actually for my scenerio, i can ignore values in 2 seconds. After 2 seconds later, it should recalculate moving logic from current position.

Answer (score 1):

What you can use is either .throttle or .debounce, I think in your case throttle will be more beneficial since it does not pause after receiving values.
so if you want to do it specifically for the true value you need to do the following:

```
motionManager.motionSubject
    .filter { $0 == true } // will only emit through values which answer this query
    .throttle(for: .milliseconds(2000), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main, latest: true) // will publish the latest value after 2 seconds delay since the first pulishment
    .sink(receiveValue: { [weak self] isMoving in
        self?.isMoving = isMoving
    }).store(in: &subscription)
```

Comment: Actually `drop` throws away the values. What you are looking for is `filter`, that's the operator that emits the values that meet the specified criteria. `drop` does the exact opposite, it throws away the values that meet the criteria.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I updated my answer